# Why is my amplify federated sign-in in react native adding an extra 'https'?

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, facebook-login, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am using a manual auth configuration in my react native app to add OAuth to my react native app. I have followed all of the steps outlined [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js) for Google and Facebook.

My problem is when I click on the button I have created in the front-end that redirects me to a federated sign-in, there is an extra 'https' in the link.

In AWS Cognito User Pools, my sign in and sign out URLS are set to myapp:// and have configured my hosted UI in the AWS console. I have also set the hosted UI url to the OAuth Redirect URI's in both facebook and google for my app clients.

This is my aws configuration in react native:

```
export default awsConfig = {
    Auth: {
      "aws_project_region": "us-west-2",
      identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:*******',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      userPoolId: '************'
      userPoolWebClientId: '*************'
      oauth: {
        domain: "https://myapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        scope: [
            "email",
            "openid",
        ],
        redirectSignIn: process.env.NODE_ENV === "myapp://",
        redirectSignOut: process.env.NODE_ENV === "myapp://",
        responseType: "code"
      },
      federationTarget: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
    }
}
```

In my case, the problem occurs when I click either the "Sign in with Facebook" or "Sign in with Google" buttons.

[image: iOS React Native App]

This is what comes up when I click either link:

[image: Safari cannot open page]

and the whole url is `https://https//aspen-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=false&response_type=code&client_id=****&identity_provider=Google&scope=email%20openid&state=****&code_challenge=xQX-****&code_challenge_method=S256`

As you can see, there is an extra `https`, and I don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `awsConfig`, I took out the 'https://' of the oauth.domain and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

The problem did not happen on my side, but you may try to do

```
import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports'; 
awsconfig.oauth.domain = awsconfig.oauth.domain.substring(8)
```

So that you won't have to remove the leading "https://" again whenever you run `amplify pull` in the future.